# How do I specify "the word under the cursor" on VIM's commandline?

Tags: vim, command-line

I want to write a command that specifies "the word under the cursor" in VIM.  For instance, let's say I have the cursor on a word and I make it appear twice.  For instance, if the word is "abc" and I want "abcabc" then I could type:

```
:s/\(abc\)/\1\1/
```

But then I'd like to be able to move the cursor to "def" and use the same command to change it to "defdef":

```
:s/\(def\)/\1\1/
```

How can I write the command in the commandline so that it does this?

```
:s/\(*whatever is under the commandline*\)/\1\1
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`<cword>` is the word under the cursor (:help `<cword>`).

You can nmap a command to it, or this series of keystrokes for the lazy will work:

```
b #go to beginning of current word
yw #yank to register
```

Then, when you are typing in your pattern you can hit `<control-r>0<enter>` which will paste in your command the contents of the 0-th register.

You can also make a command for this like:

```
:nmap <leader>w :s/\(<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr>\)/
```

Which will map hitting '' and 'w' at the same time to replace your command line with

```
:s/\(<currentword>\)/
```

Comment: I do appreciate the great answer, but I would probably suggest the `yiw` over `byw` only because of muscle memory. In the scenario where your cursor already happens to be on the first character in the word, you **must** omit the `b` and simply type `yw` vs you **may** omit the `i` in `yiw`. Accidents can happen, and fixing a mistake is certainly more keypresses :)

Comment: Years later, an addition: you might consider binding a key to *just* the part that expands `<cword>`, using `cnoremap`. I just found this answer, and I have bound <C-W> to `<C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR>` which makes it possible to type, e.g., `:s/\(<C-W>\)/\1\1/` and have the cword inserted for me.

Answer (score 161):

While in command-line mode, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will insert the word under the cursor.

See the help for `c_CTRL-R` for a listing of all the other special registers:

```
:help c_CTRL-R
```

Answer (score 34):

```
yiwP
```

`yiw`: Yank inner word (the word under the cursor). This command also moves the cursor to the beginning of the word.

`P`: Paste before the cursor.

You can then map the e.g.: `< ALT > - D` to this command:

```
:nmap < ALT >-D yiwP
```

Comment: The question was specifically about specifying "the word under the cursor" from Vim's commandline, not from command mode

Answer (score 15):

Another easy way to do this is to use the `*` command.

In regular mode, when over a word, type

```
*:s//\0\0<Enter>
```

`*` makes the search pattern the current word (e.g. \<abc\>).

`:s//` does a substitution using the current search pattern, and `\0` in the replacement
section is the matched string.

You can then repeat this behaviour, say over word "def", by either typing the same again, or by typing

```
*@:
```

`@:` just repeats the last ex command, without a need for an <Enter>, in this case the substitution.

You can also record a quick macro to do this using the `q` command

```
qd*:s//\0\0<Enter>q
```

Then repeat it to your hearts content by typing

```
@d
```

when over a word you want to double.  As this is only one character less than the prior solution, it may not be worth it to you - unless you will be doing other ex-commands between the word-doubling, which would change the behaviour of `@:`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslashes within the mapping. You can also include the substitution string within the mapping.

```
:nmap <leader>w :s/\\(<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr>\\)/\\1\\1<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ywPx
```

will do what you describe.

```
ywPxw
```

will also advance the cursor to the next word.

Comment: The question was specifically about specifying "the word under the cursor" from Vim's commandline, not from command mode

Comment: Please describe answers like that, every letter in the command.

Answer (score 1):

@[user11211](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11211/user11211) [has the most straightforward way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/82120/1084) to duplicate the word under cursor:

```
yiwP
```

yank inner word (moves cursor to start of word), paste (before cursor).

eg. straigh[t]forward ----> straightforwar[d]straightforward

[] is cursor

To elaborate...

You probably want to have the cursor following your duplicated word:

```
yiwPea
```

straigh[t]forward ----> straightforwardstraightforward[]

NOTE:

```
yiw
```

is yank inner word (without whitespace)

```
yaw
```

is yank all word (including trailing whitespace).

```
yawPea
```

is therefore duplicate word including whitespace, and position cursor.

straigh[t]forward ----> straightforward straightforward[]

Comment: The question was specifically about specifying "the word under the cursor" from Vim's *commandline*, not from command mode.

Comment: You can use any of the normal (command mode) commands above within command mode, by simply preceding them with :normal ... for example, :normal yiwP will do the same as yiwP in normal mode.  This is of course, the slower way to do what you were asking.

Answer (score -1):

```
" count word  (case sensitive)
nmap <F4> :%s/\(<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr>\)//gn<cr>
```

Comment: could you comment on what this does?

Comment: This uses the `n` flag to the `:substitute` command to print out how many times the word under the cursor appears in the current buffer. Quite clever, but not actually an answer to this question.