# vi command line equivalent to CTRL-]?

Tags: vi, vim, ctags

I'm trying to map my own shortcuts in vi.
I want to be able to open a splitted window containing the declaration of the function I'm calling the shortcut on.
something like this in my vimrc:

`nmap <unique> <silent> <Leader>tg :exe 'vsplit'\| equivalent of <C-]>`

but what's the equivalent of C-] in command mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open vim at the line containing the tag `foobar` type this at the shell commandline:

```
vim -t foobar
```

To jump to the same tag on the vim commandline type:

```
:tag foobar
```

If you want to split the window and jump to the tag in the new window type this in vim's commandline:

```
:stag foobar
```

If you want a keystroke that specifies "the word under the cursor", then according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642/how-do-i-specify-the-word-under-the-cursor-on-vims-commandline), you can use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to get that:

`:tag CTRL+R CTRL+W`

You can also use :

```
:nmap <leader>w :tag <c-r>=expand("<cword>")<c-r>
```

Now typing `<leader>+w` (which is <kbd>\</kbd> in my setup, so I'd press <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>) will be the same as typing `:tag <word under the cursor>`

Comment: but how can I call tag or stag with the keyword under the cursor ? {ident} doesn't seem to work..

Comment: yes, but I need it as a command for my key bindings
I tried:
nmap <unique> <silent> <Leader>tg :exe 'vsplit \| tag <C-r> <C-w>'<CR>
but  it didn't work... I just got my vi splitted

Comment: thaks, expand("<cword>") was just what I needed !

Comment: this is the line I added in my rc file for those who could be interested:
nmap <unique> <silent> <Leader>tv :exe 'vertical stag <c-r>=expand("<cword>")<CR>'<CR>

Answer (score 3):

See :help CTRL-]:

> CTRL-]   Jump to the definition of the
>   keyword under the    cursor.  Same as
>   ":tag {ident}", where {ident} is the
>      keyword under or after cursor.

#### Edit

Not sure if there is a built-in for this, but the following seems to match the keyword "under or after" the cursor:

```
matchstr(getline('.'), '\%'.col('.').'c\s*\zs\k\+')
```

Comment: seems like {ident} doesn't match the keyword under the cursor. :(
it just has to be replaced by the tag you want.
got any idea to get the keyword under the cursor ?

Comment: yes, {ident} is for syntax highlighting in vim's documentation

Answer (score 0):

you could also write (to map it for example to Ctrl-Q):

```
:nmap <C-Q> <C-]>
```

you could also consider :nn[oremap] in such cases to avoid nested/recursive mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to the definition of the word under the cursor with `exe "tag " . expand("<cword>")`. The expand function replaces special tokens with their meaning - this includes a filename under the cursor, the current file name, etc.  See Vim's help for the expand() function for the full set.

Alternatively you could use the :normal command, which lets you execute normal-mode key sequences from an :ex command.